# Colorized hexdump

Tags: visualization, grid-layouts, binary

I have this hexdump command that I am writing to display a nicely printed hexdump into a mathematic grid. I want to be able to specify regions that I can highlight, however I am stuck being only able to highlight 1 region. How can I improve my code so that I can print my hexdump correctly? Here is what I have so far

```
(* Helper function to translate offset + lengths into a format that I can then use to highlight cells *)
CreateTuplesFromOffsetAndLength[offset_, length_] := 
 Module[{elementsPerRow = 16, startRow, startColumn, endRow, 
   endColumn, rows, columns, 
   tuples},(*Calculate the starting and ending rows and columns*)
  
  startRow = Quotient[offset, elementsPerRow] + 1;
  startColumn = Mod[offset, elementsPerRow] + 1;
  endRow = Quotient[offset + length - 1, elementsPerRow] + 1;
  endColumn = Mod[offset + length - 1, elementsPerRow] + 1;
  (*Generate the tuples*)
  tuples = Flatten[
    Table[{row, col}, {row, startRow, endRow}, {col, 
      If[row == startRow, startColumn, 1], 
      If[row == endRow, endColumn, elementsPerRow]}], 1];
  tuples]

(*Read the binary data from a file*)
filenname = "/tmp/example";
binaryData = Import[filename, "Byte"];

(*Convert to hexadecimal with two digits (leading zeros)*)

hexData = IntegerString[binaryData, 16, 2];

(* Regions to colorize *)
colorizedRegion1 = 
 CreateTuplesFromOffsetAndLength[1, 1]
colorizedRegion2 = CreateTuplesFromOffsetAndLength[0, 1]

(*Function to apply colorization*)

colorizeFunction = 
  Function[c, (MapAt[Item[#, Background -> c] &, #1, #2] &)];

(*Group data for formatting,pad with empty strings*)

groupedData = Partition[hexData, 16, 16, {1, 1}, ""];

(* Apply colorization to region(s) *)
colorizedData1 = 
 Fold[colorizeFunction[Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9]], groupedData, 
  colorizedRegion1]
colorizedData2 = 
 Fold[colorizeFunction[Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9]], groupedData, 
  colorizedRegion2]
colorizedData = Join[colorizedData1, colorizedData2]

(*Define headers*)

headers = 
  Prepend[Table[IntegerString[i, 16, 2], {i, 0, 15}], "Offset"];

(*Create data with addresses*)

formattedData = 
  MapIndexed[Flatten@{IntegerString[First[#2] - 1, 16, 8], #1} &, 
   colorizedData];

(*Format and display the hexdump with header using Grid*)

gray = RGBColor@"#d5d8de";
Grid[Prepend[formattedData, headers], Frame -> All, 
 FrameStyle -> Thickness[1.25], Background -> {{1 -> gray}, {1 -> gray}
   }, ItemSize -> {{1 -> {Automatic}, {2}}, {2, {2}}}]
```

This will result in an output of
[image]

in particular, notice that it simply stacks the data rather overlaying them ontop of each other in the grid. How can I fix this?

UPDATE/SOLUTION:

I have fixed up and put the functionality into a usable function if anyone is ever interested in using this

```
hexdump[filename_, regions_] := 
  Module[{binaryData, hexData, colorizedRegions, 
    colorizedTuplesAndColors, colorizeFunction, groupedData, 
    colorizedData, headers, formattedData, 
    grid},(*Helper function to translate offset+
   lengths into a format for highlighting cells*)
   CreateTuplesFromOffsetAndLength[offset_, length_] := 
    Module[{elementsPerRow = 16, startRow, startColumn, endRow, 
      endColumn, tuples}, 
     startRow = Quotient[offset, elementsPerRow] + 1;
     startColumn = Mod[offset, elementsPerRow] + 1;
     endRow = Quotient[offset + length - 1, elementsPerRow] + 1;
     endColumn = Mod[offset + length - 1, elementsPerRow] + 1;
     tuples = 
      Flatten[Table[{row, col}, {row, startRow, endRow}, {col, 
         If[row == startRow, startColumn, 1], 
         If[row == endRow, endColumn, elementsPerRow]}], 1];
     tuples];
   (*Read the binary data from a file*)
   
   binaryData = Import[filename, "Byte"];
   (*Convert to hexadecimal with two digits (leading zeros)*)
   
   hexData = IntegerString[binaryData, 16, 2];
   (*Convert regions to tuples and use the specified color for each \
region*)
   colorizedRegions = regions;
   colorizedTuplesAndColors = 
    Map[{CreateTuplesFromOffsetAndLength @@ #[[1]], #[[2]]} &, 
     colorizedRegions];
   (*Function to apply colorization*)
   colorizeFunction = 
    Function[{data, positions, color}, 
     MapAt[Item[#, Background -> color] &, data, positions]];
   (*Group data for formatting,pad with empty strings*)
   
   groupedData = Partition[hexData, 16, 16, {1, 1}, ""];
   (*Apply colorization to each region*)
   colorizedData = 
    Fold[colorizeFunction[#1, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, groupedData, 
     colorizedTuplesAndColors];
   (*Define headers*)
   
   headers = 
    Prepend[Table[IntegerString[i, 16, 2], {i, 0, 15}], "Offset"];
   (*Create data with addresses*)
   formattedData = 
    MapIndexed[
     Flatten@{IntegerString[(First[#2] - 1)*16, 16, 4], #1} &, 
     colorizedData];
   (*Format and display the hexdump with header using Grid*)
   
   gray = RGBColor@"#d5d8de";
   grid = 
    Grid[Prepend[formattedData, headers], Frame -> All, 
     FrameStyle -> Thickness[1.25], 
     Background -> {{1 -> gray}, {1 -> gray}}, 
     ItemSize -> {{1 -> {Automatic}, {2}}, {2, {2}}}];
   (*Return the grid*)
   grid];
```

Example usage

```
hexdump["/tmp/example/test", {{{1, 3}, 
   Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9]}, {{10, 5}, 
   Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9]}, {{5, 4}, Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9]}}]
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following two lines:

```
(*Regions to colorize*)
colorizedRegion = 
  Catenate@(CreateTuplesFromOffsetAndLength @@@ {{1, 1}, {3, 2}, {6, 1}, {25, 3}});

(*Apply colorization to region(s)*)
colorizedData = colorizeFunction[Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9]][groupedData, colorizedRegion]
```

[image]